# Create S3 Bucket in another Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, role

I have an ec2 instance configured with an IAM Role to read S3 in its own account. I configured a cross account role in another AWS account that has rights to create S3 buckets. I then gave the role that the ec2 instance is assigned access to the use the cross account role.

When I try to create the s3 bucket, it tries to create it in it's own account. How do I tell the aws cli to create the bucket in the other account?

Comment: have you read this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html

Comment: I have, it doesn't answer my question on how to create buckets in the other account. It mentions how to manage permissions of an existing bucket.

Comment: Can you paste the policy for your role? If possible.

Answer (score 0):

Refer cross account python script https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx70F69I9G8TYG/How-to-enable-cross-account-access-to-the-AWS-Management-Console

When you run it you will automatically redirect to cross account AWS Console...and if you don't want to run python script..login through switch role option.

Through cli you must have to run sts command...for example aws sts assume-role --role-arn crossSccountRoleARN  --role-session-name "DemoRoleSession"  > /tmp/assume-role-output.txt